# Virt-manager QEMU/KVM

Tags: virtualization, 20.04, qemu

after updating to 20.04 I have "sudo systemctl restart libvirtd.service" every time.
Can it be repaired? I tried remove and install again but it didn't work for me. 
UPDATE: It's the same even under fresh install of 20.04.

LOGS here: https://imgur.com/a/0QV9YUB

Comment: Have you tried `sudo systemctl enable libvirtd.service`

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with "I have sudo systemctl restart ... every time", do you have to issue it so something works at all - or is something else restarting it all the time?

Comment: @Ravexina Just now, didn't work for me.

Comment: @christian-ehrhardt It works, but only after I restart the service. Otherwise not, it stucks at "QEMU/KVM - Connecting"

Comment: @robinj - hmm clearly works for me. Since you say it doesn't work for you after a fresh 20.04 install could you open a bug and attach 1. what command exactly won't work (inclduing the error messages) 2. journalctl -u libvirtd 3. systemctl status libvirtd. Feel free to ping me here if I don't see the bug in time.

Comment: @Christian Ehrhardt Thanks for help. I already did another fresh install as I blamed Canon drivers too. But it seems its QEMU/KVM related.
I attached logs screenshot here:
https://imgur.com/a/0QV9YUB
I put descriptions under images.

Comment: Interesting, my first through would have been (since it is socket activated) that your virt-manager might not trigger that. We are exceeding the capacity of comments on here, would you mind following me to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virt-manager/+bug/1876266 for this?

Comment: @Christian Ehrhardt Hi, thank you for your help. I'll post all data on launchpad tmr.